# How to convert the array-like string into array with js?

Tags: javascript

There is a array-like string.

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "30"
    ["date"]=>
    string(10) "2018-10-14"
  }
}
```

How to convert it into an array in js?
This is how the array-like string create in my case: ajax in my js call a php file which select a mysql database and var_dump the result into js.

Comment: What you've shown isn't valid code, nor does it look like an array-like string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In php side,$result is a array,not `var_dump($result)`.

```
echo (json_encode($result));
```

In js side:

```
  data = xmlHttp.responseText;  
  data = JSON.parse(data)[0]; 
  console.log(data.date)
```

It shows `2018-10-14`.